# BroadcastReceiver recieves string but onresume does not upate textView with value

Tags: android, textview, broadcastreceiver, onresume

I am having some real problem with this issue over the last few days and would like some help.
this section of code is from a music app that I'm building and it resides in the main activity.

everything works as expected with exception to this.
the UI only gets updated with a new song title if the screen is on and the app is in the foreground. if the app is in the background or the screen is off the textView is not updated. it is "only" updated once the screen is switched on again and the app is in the foreground, where it waits till a new track is about to play then it updates the textView

i need to understand why is this, that logcat can easily see each new song title regaurdless wether the phone is on or phone yet broadcast is delivering null in phone screen off or app in background state

thank you

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        new IntentFilter("uiTrackUpdater");
        Log.d("res", "on pause ");
    }

    /* onResume the app fires up and continues to work as expected.
       however the textView is blank, because for some reason beyond
       my understanding the songtitle that got received in the BroadcastReceiver
       just wont show itself here.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        stit = intent.getStringExtra("songTitle");
        TextView trackDetails = findViewById(R.id.sTitle);
        trackDetails.setText(stit); //stit is always null onResume

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("uiTrackUpdater"));
       Log.d("res", "resumed");
    }

    /*  the BroadcastReceiver works as expected. it picks up each new
        song title that is being sent from a broadcast that is triggered
        in a separate service class and while the screen is on or the app
        is in the foreground then and only then does BroadcastReceiver update
        the textView (trackdetails) but once the app is in the background or
        the screen is off the BroadcastReceiver does not update the textView
     */
    public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView trackDetails = findViewById(R.id.sTitle);
            String songtitle = intent.getStringExtra("songTitle");
            trackDetails.setText(songtitle);

            /*  the strange thing is this.
                The Log.d clearly shows (ONLY in the "logcat pain") each new song title
                that is currently being played even when the phone is in the
                background, yet when I try to read from the songtitle variable
                out from this BroadcastReceiver method the code show up as null.....
```

its really driving me crazy as i have tried so many different way to get the song title out from this method

```
             */
            Log.d("res","titleCount " + songtitle);
        }
```

Comment: just want to know if someone can cast me a life line here.

Answer (score 0):

this situation is solved. I was trying to reference a variable another class that was not static. so I made the variable "titleN" a public static string in rwrstrmserv.class than in the main activity class I dropped the code below in the onResume method

results now are, if the player is in the background or partially covered then on resume the textView will be updated with the current track title

```
rwrstrmserv rwrs = new rwrstrmserv();
        TextView trackDetails = findViewById(R.id.sTitle);
        trackDetails.setText(titleN); `
```